# How to make something use the previous value of an integer even after the integer changes

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx

I am new to programming, using JavaFX at the moment for a personal organization tool. I have showed here an arraylist of buttons(called books) and stages(called bookStages), a VBox called addBook, and an Int called bookButtonCount set to 0.

```
addBook.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
@Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
        addBooks.getChildren().add(books.get(bookButtonCount));

        books.get(bookButtonCount).setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
           @Override
              public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                 bookStages.get(bookButtonCount).show();
                 System.out.println(bookButtonCount);
              }
        });
        bookButtonCount++;
   }
});
```

The first button adds a button from the "books" arraylist to the VBox. The button from the vbox is supposed to open a stage from the stage arraylist. You should be able to fire the button multiple times, each time adding a new button to the vbox and setting that button to open its own stage. Though it seems that using bookButtonCount as a reference will not work because each time you press a button from the books arraylist in the vbox, it checks for the current value of bookButtonCount.(Which changes as more buttons are added) and opens the wrong stage.

Is there any way to have the action for the button be saved with the value of bookButtonCount at the time it is set only?

If not, how should I set this up?
Here is some more bits of code that may be useful:

```
ArrayList<Stage> bookStages = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<Button> books = new ArrayList();
   for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
     books.add(new Button("Book " + (i+1)));
     bookStages.add(new Stage());
     bookStages.get(i).setTitle("Book " + (i+1));
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just register the handler when you create the button and stage:

```
ArrayList<Stage> bookStages = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<Button> books = new ArrayList();
for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
    Button button = new Button("Book " + (i+1));
    books.add(button);
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    bookStages.add(stage);
    stage.setTitle("Book " + (i+1));
    button.setOnAction(e -> stage.show());
}
```

and

```
addBook.setOnAction(e -> {
    addBooks.getChildren().add(books.get(bookButtonCount));
    bookButtonCount++ ;
});
```